# Is there well-defined behavior for how React rerenders after receiving multiple simultaneous events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, dom-events

Let's say I have a React component that may receive multiple events that perform state changes after one interaction, as shown below:

```js
const {useRef, useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [_, setState] = useState(null);

  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  renderCount.current += 1;
  console.log("rendering");
  
  return (
  <div>
    {`Render count: ${renderCount.current} `}
    
    <span onClick={() => { 
      console.log("span clicked"); 
      setState({}); 
    }}>
      <button onClick={() => { 
        console.log("button clicked"); 
        setState({}); 
      }}>Send click events</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( < App / > );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In the above example, after pressing the button to fire the click events, both event handlers run, but React batches the state updates to only rerender once.

However, if I attach these event handlers directly on the native HTML elements, as shown below, React rerenders twice per interaction, or rather after each event handler.

```js
const {useRef, useState, useEffect} = React;

function App() {
  const [_, setState] = useState(null);
  const spanRef = useRef();
  const btnRef = useRef();

  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  renderCount.current += 1;
  console.log("rendering");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler1 = () => { 
      console.log("span clicked"); 
      setState({}); 
    };
    
    const handler2 = () => { 
      console.log("button clicked"); 
      setState({}); 
    };
    
    const span = spanRef.current;
    span.addEventListener("click", handler1);
    
    const btn = btnRef.current;
    btn.addEventListener("click", handler2);

    return () => {
      span.removeEventListener("click", handler1);
      btn.removeEventListener("click", handler2);
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
  <div>
    {`Render count: ${renderCount.current} `}
    
    <span ref={spanRef}>
      <button ref={btnRef}>Send click events</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( < App / > );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I suspect this has something to do with React's synthetic event system, but I'm trying to understand the behavior exactly. For instance, will React always immediately rerender state updates after native event listeners? If so, do effects still run in between rerenders, or are they deferred until all event handlers have been executed?

Either answers or references to official documentation are appreciated. And to clarify, this isn't for a particular project or problem I'm solving, I'm just trying to better understand React's behavior.

Comment: There are no guarantees in React how often anything is rendered. Your render function should be pure and always return the same elements given the same state (which your `renderCount` ref violates), so React could do anything as an optimisation. Realistically, React will have to synchronously change state, re-render and apply effects from within the `setState` call if there is no batching "context".

Comment: To clarify, the `renderCount` ref is solely there to show the different batching behavior between examples; it's intentionally violating React principles for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is *(very probably)* that,

- when attaching the event listeners to the native HTML elements with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), clicking with the mouse invokes the event handlers *asynchronously*, whereas
- the [React events](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#react-event-object) invoke the event handlers [*synchronously*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

I'd expect this is not well documented by React, because you ask about the order in which things happen, which you are not supposed to care about in React.

I would even say that React might change the internal behavior at any time without changing the basic concept (e.g. the guarantees React makes about state).

Anyway, I'll try to make sense of it here *(I'm sorry, I need to guess a bit)* ...

#### React events

Probably a relevant fact is that [React attaches event handlers at the root](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#react-event-object-caveats).

You can confirm that by logging the `.currentTarget` of the [`event.nativeEvent` property](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#react-event-object-properties), e.g.:

```
<span onClick={ event => {
    console.log("span clicked:", event.nativeEvent.currentTarget, event.nativeEvent.target);
    setState({});
}}>
    <button onClick={ event => {
        console.log("button clicked:", event.nativeEvent.currentTarget, event.nativeEvent.target);
        setState({});
    }}>Send click events</button>
</span>
```

#### Native events

In javascript, nothing can run in parallel, so normal click events,
initiated by e.g. the mouse, can not be executed while other javascript code is still running.

So the click events are queued, and each is executed only when the [call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_Stack) *(aka "execution stack")* is empty.

Therefore,

- the **button click** handler is executed together with the `setState` and the re-render of the virtual DOM,
- then the **span click** handler can be executed, with the second `setState` and the re-render,
- then the actual browser DOM is updated.

#### Sythetic events

I *assume* that React handles the events from multiple elements with the same internal event handler, and
invokes the attached handlers using [synthetic events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

As synthetic events are always executed synchronously, all attached event handlers are executed before the internal React event handler returns, i.e.

- **button onClick** is executed, together with `setState`, but then, instead of the re-render,
- the **span click** handler is executed, with the second `setState`.
- *Then* the re-render and DOM update happens.

#### Inspect the events

It's not possible to inspect or "tap into" the already attached event handlers
*(apart from browser dev-tools like "inspect node" and [getEventListeners](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#getEventListeners-function))*, but you can further examine the order in which the events are executed if you

- add both, the native event handlers and the React event handlers to the elements,
- add another `console.log` in a [`microtask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask), which will illustrate that the call stack was empty.

E.g.:

```
const handler1 = () => {
    console.log("Native event: spanRef click");
    queueMicrotask(() => { console.log('Native event: spanRef click (microtask)'); } )
    setState({});
};

const handler2 = () => {
    console.log("Native event: buttonRef click");
    queueMicrotask( () => { console.log('Native event: buttonRef click (microtask)'); } )
    setState({});
};

// ...

<span ref={ spanRef } onClick={ () => {
    console.log('React event: span onClick');
    queueMicrotask( () => {
        console.log('React event: span onClick (microtask)');
    })
    setState({});
}}>
    <button ref={ buttonRef } onClick={ () => {
        console.log( 'React event: button onClick' );
        queueMicrotask( () => {
            console.log( 'React event: button onClick (microtask)' );
        })
        setState({});
    }}>Send click events</button>
</span>
```

Which will log after a mouse click on the button:

```
rendering 1
Native event: buttonRef click               \
rendering 2                                  | native button event completely executed
Native event: buttonRef click (microtask)   /
Native event: spanRef click                 \
rendering 4                                  | native span event completely executed
Native event: spanRef click (microtask)     /
     (Here probably Reacts internal root event handler executed)
React event: button onClick                 \
React event: span onClick                    |
rendering 6                                  | All React events executed
React event: button onClick (microtask)      |
React event: span onClick (microtask)       /
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! This clears up most of my questions. And from my own experimentation, I found that effects always seem to run directly after a rerender, even between native events. I guess my only remaining question is if it's somehow possible for async native events (like a WebSocket message) to come in and be handled during React's handler execution. Or is it guaranteed that these phases are separated by at least one render?

Comment: I'd say no, there is no guarantee. But as it is (and if my assumptions are right), no event can be handled before React's handlers are finished, because the execution stack is not empty. I.e. you can indeed "freeze" the whole app if you do some heavy calculation inside one handler.